# using TryGetValue for nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested

I have this dictionary:

```
 private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

how can i use TryGetValue in this?

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
 MyDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
```

key is an integer and value is an empty string.

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ is a very poor substitute for `cannot convert Dictionary<> to string`. Always include full error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use in the following way.

I am getting the right value back. Please execute the same.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var value = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "Value1" }, { "Key2", "Value2" } };
            dictionary.Add(1, value);

            Dictionary<string, string> result;


            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(1, out result))
            {
                foreach (var key in result.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: b{1}", key, result[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I divide the key part and value part of the "result"?

Answer (score 1):

value will be a `Dictionary<string, string>` not a `string` so you would need

```
Dictionary<string, string> value;

if (MyDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)) 
{
    // do something with value
}
```

Then you could call `TryGetValue` on `value` to find a value keyed with a particular string.